# Logging local page load times in browser

Tags: performance, browser

I am trying to generate a log of page load times (time from first byte of HTML to the `onload` event) from my actual browsing habits. An ideal solution would produce, after performing a google search for example, a log something like this:

```
http://google.com/ 523
https://www.google.com/search?q=asdf 1003
```

Where the pages took 523ms and 1003 to load.

A firefox or chrome extension that works on linux or mac would be ideal, as I'm trying to track in the context of normal everyday browsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install the [NetExport Firebug extension](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/netexport/), it will allow you to export all collected and computed data from the Firebug Net panel as a HTTP Archive (HAR) format file (based on JSON).

You can then view this file that includes load times using [HAR Viewer](http://www.softwareishard.com/har/viewer/) or [other tools](https://superuser.com/questions/360992/what-format-does-google-chrome-developer-tools-save-data-as/361833#361833).

Answer (score 0):

You need Fiddler. http://www.fiddlertool.com

Another great tool which does what you requested in the comments is dynatrace ajax. http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/ It hooks into the browser and keeps metrics on actual render and js times. http://ejohn.org/blog/deep-tracing-of-internet-explorer/

Comment: A proxy won't work -- I need actual load times in a browser, including time spent rendering and running javascript.

Comment: Added another suggestion which does what you need. Works in IE and FF.

Comment: Looks like it's windows-only, which I have no access to. I've edited the question to reflect this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Gavin, 
Try using the FireBug Plugin in FireFox. http://getfirebug.com/
It shows you when the file started and stopped loading relative to all the other files.

Worth checking out.

Regards,
Ninad

Comment: I can look at the times I need in firebug/Chrome developer tools, but what I'm looking for here is logging -- I need an entire day's worth of time to analyze.

Comment: Check if you looking for Web analytics check out piwik its really nice  [link](http://piwik.org) or if you are looking for alerts and page loading times check [link](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/)